# Importing individual lodash functions instead of whole lodash project

Tags: node.js, npm, underscore.js, lodash, npm-install

I see that importing the entire lodash library takes up quite a bit of space on disk:

```
$ du . | grep lodash
1696    ./lodash/fp
5000    ./lodash
```

In my code I am just doing

```
require('lodash');
```

and my package.json just looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "lodash": "^4.6.1",
   ...
}
```

Note that this is for a backend project only, not for web, if that makes a difference.

So my question is - what is the latest way of just importing a slice of lodash (just the functions I need) without importing the whole damn thing?

It looks like here are some answers:

https://gist.github.com/callumlocke/bbfc524eaed6b3556dab

My guess is that I should be using the dot syntax for my backend project:

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "lodash.X": "^4.6.1",
   ...
}
```

and then import it like so:

```
 require('lodash.X');
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Two ways

There are two ways to do it:

1. You can use packages with the individual functions and e.g. `require('lodash.head')`
2. You can use the full package and e.g. `require('lodash/head')`

### `require('lodash.head')`

You install the package with individual function:

```
npm install --save lodash.head
```

This adds this to package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "lodash.head": "^4.0.1"
}
```

You use it with:

```
var head = require('lodash.head');
```

### `require('lodash/head')`

You install the full `lodash` package:

```
npm install --save lodash
```

This adds this to package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "lodash": "^4.17.4"
}
```

You use it with:

```
var head = require('lodash/head');
```

### More examples

More complex example:

You can have `_` with two functions that you need:

```
var head = require('lodash.head');
var tail = require('lodash.tail');
var _ = {pick, defaults};
```

Similar effect, different style:

```
var _ = {
  head: require('lodash.head'),
  tail: require('lodash.tail'),
};
```

### Explanation

If you want only some part of lodash, like e.g. lodash.pick then use:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.pick

For more examples of single functions packaged as modules see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lodash-modularized

You can also use custom builds, see:

- https://lodash.com/custom-builds

When you use the full package and import only the functions that you need with:

```
var _ = {
  head: require('lodash/head'),
  tail: require('lodash/tail'),
};
```

Then some tools like Webpack may be able to optimize your build to include only the code that you actually use. When you import the entire lodash with:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

then static analysis cannot be sure which function will be used at runtime so it's harder to optimize well and usually more code is included in the build than is actually needed.

Comment: Individual method packages will be removed in v5 of lodash. See https://lodash.com/per-method-packages

Answer (score 5):

Using ES6 modules, this could be done like this as well:

```
import isEqual from 'lodash.isequal';
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43479515/1417223)

Comment: nah this still installs all of lodash, look in node_modules.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Note that the import is made of a modularized function (compared to `import isEqual from 'lodash/isequal'`).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402664/9555168), you can use `lodash-es` as an alternative. Instead of running `npm install lodash ...` for every single lodash function that you want to use. By using `lodash-es` you only need to install it once, then you can import whatever lodash function you want to use in your code.

Install `lodash-es` using NPM:

```sh
npm install lodash-es
```

To import specific function, said `isEqual`,

```js
import { isEqual } from "lodash-es";
```

Now, you can use `isEqual` function inside your code.

```js
const a = {a: "a"};
const b = {b: "b"};

if (isEqual(a, b)) {
  //do something
}
```

Although, this is for backend project only in your case. But, FYI and other readers who may land here, `webpack` plus `lodash-es` can reduce my bundle size down to `18 kb` from `78 kb` with general `lodash`.