# How to Import a Single Lodash Function?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Using webpack, I'm trying to import [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual) since `lodash` seems to be importing everything. I've tried doing the following with no success:

```
import { isEqual } from 'lodash'

import isEqual from 'lodash/lang'

import isEqual from 'lodash/lang/isEqual'

import { isEqual } from 'lodash/lang'

import { isEqual } from 'lodash/lang'
```

Comment: Do you mean https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.isequal ?

Comment: no, I would like to import other functions as well

Comment: In my understanding, you can now import one by one or all of them, no middle ground. I would recommand the one by one even if it add a lot of dependancies in package.json, it will be easier to test and upgrade method one by one later, rather than all of them in one step

Comment: `lodash` documents every valid way and its impact https://lodash.com/per-method-packages.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

You can install `lodash.isequal` as a single module without installing the whole *lodash* package like so:

```
npm install --save lodash.isequal
```

When using ECMAScript 5 and CommonJS modules, you then import it like this:

```
var isEqual = require('lodash.isequal');
```

Using ES6 modules, this would be:

```
import isEqual from 'lodash.isequal';
```

And you can use it in your code:

```
const obj1 = {username: 'peter'};
const obj2 = {username: 'peter'};
const obj3 = {username: 'gregory'};

isEqual(obj1, obj2) // returns true
isEqual(obj1, obj3) // returns false
```

Source: [Lodash documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.isequal)

After importing, you can use the `isEqual` function in your code. Note that it is not a part of an object named `_` if you import it this way, so you 
*don't* reference it with `_.isEqual`, but directly with `isEqual`.

**Alternative: Using `lodash-es`**

As pointed out by [@kimamula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402664/1253156):

With webpack 4 and [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) 4.17.7 and higher, this code works.

```
import { isEqual } from 'lodash-es';
```

This is because webpack 4 supports the [sideEffects](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free) flag and `lodash-es` 4.17.7 and higher includes the flag (which is set to `false`).

**Why Not Use the Version With the Slash?**
Other answers to this question suggest that you can also use a dash instead of a dot, like so:

```
import isEqual from 'lodash/isequal';
```

This works, too, but there are two minor drawbacks:

- You have to install the whole *lodash* package (`npm install --save lodash`), not just the small separate *lodash.isequal* package; storage space is cheap and CPUs are fast, so you may not care about this
- The resulting bundle when using tools like webpack will be slightly bigger; I found out that bundle sizes with a minimal code example of `isEqual` are on average 28% bigger (tried webpack 2 and webpack 3, with or without Babel, with or without Uglify)

Comment: Doesn't work for me for some reason, I am getting `_ is not defined` when using `_.isEquals`

Comment: @cvDv, But it is not supposed to use like `_.isEqual`, you should use directly `isEqual`

Comment: hmm im still get `isEqual` is undefined, I added `import isEqual from 'lodash.isequal'` to the top and below is just a `export const functionName` using isEquals

Comment: Have you actually installed the module? npm i --save lodash.isequal

Comment: yeah looks like wasn't running watch with webpack so restarting it worked -_-
 ...thanks for the help

Comment: I am trying to use differenceWith and import { differenceWith } from 'lodash.differenceWith'; does not work for me. Getting lodash_differenceWith_1.default is not a function

Comment: Think you actually need slash not period, ie  `import isEqual from 'lodash/isequal'`. At least, that's what works for me on Win 10.

Comment: No, it's a period. See documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.isequal

Comment: Ah. I'd just done `npm --save lodash` then `import whatever from 'lodash/whatever'`, which seemed to work (with smaller filesize) without my needing to explicitly run `npm --save lodash.whatever`. Is there any advantage to using your period method, since it seems to require running an extra `import` every time you want access to an additional function?

Comment: Sorry - I meant running an extra `npm --save` for every additional function.

Comment: `import template from 'lodash.template';` is not working and I am using Webpack and uglifyjs. `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: @thund Since this answer gets a lot of up votes, I've taken the time to compare bundle sizes when using dot (as recommended by lodash docs) and slashes, see my edited answer

Comment: @PatrickHund: That's very interesting. I agree that the overhead of having the whole lodash on your development machine is pretty trivial, especially since it eliminates the need to run `npm --save lodash.whatever` for each function separately, but the larger bundle size could certainly make it worth using the period method. I'm surprised that there's a difference, so I'm glad you ran the numbers for us.

Comment: @EvgenyFedorenko the correct way to import it is: `import differenceWith from 'lodash.differencewith'`. `lodash.differencewith` needs to be all in lowercase letters.

Comment: what about typing for the individual installed functions?

Comment: "28% bigger" of what?  The isEqual function can't be more than 300 bytes.  This seems like unnecessary hand optimization over the / version.

Comment: It should be noted that using per method packages is no longer the recommended way and will be removed in lodash 5 - https://lodash.com/per-method-packages

Comment: I have `lodash` pckg installed, and when I try to `import isEqual from "lodash/isEqual"; `my code deson't seem to be an issue, but I am to use the method `isEqual(arr1, arr2)` I get a type error `...is not a function`. Would someone know why?

Answer (score 76):

If you just want to include `isEqual` and not the rest of the `lodash` functions (useful for keeping your bundle size small), you can do this in ES6;

```
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual'
```

This is pretty much the same as what's described in [the `lodash` README](https://github.com/lodash/lodash#installation), except that there they use `require()` syntax.

```
var at = require('lodash/at');
```

Comment: This answer should work, but if you come across the error:
`isEqual.isEqual is not a function`
due to your ESM configuration, try using:
`import * as isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';`

Answer (score 39):

With webpack 4 and lodash-es 4.17.7 and higher, this code works.

```
import { isEqual } from 'lodash-es';
```

This is because webpack 4 supports [`sideEffects` flag](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free) and lodash-es 4.17.7 and higher includes the flag (which is set to `false`).

**Edit**

[As of version 1.9.0, Parcel also supports `"sideEffects": false`](https://medium.com/@devongovett/parcel-v1-9-0-tree-shaking-2x-faster-watcher-and-more-87f2e1a70f79), threrefore `import { isEqual } from 'lodash-es';` is also tree shakable with Parcel.

Comment: Excellent, I added this info to my answer, hope that's alright with you 

Comment: Awesome. This can reduce my bundle size from 78 kb to 18 kb using webpack.

Answer (score 9):

Not related to webpack but I'll add it here as a lot of people are currently moving to typescript.

You can also import a single function from lodash using `import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';` in typescript with the `esModuleInterop` flag in the compiler options (tsconfig.json)

example

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think it is worth noting [lodash documentation on per method packages](https://lodash.com/per-method-packages) to answer this question at least as of June 2020:

> Lodash methods are available in standalone per method packages like lodash.mapvalues, lodash.pickby, etc. These packages contain only the code the method depends on.
>
> However, use of these packages is ***discouraged and they will be removed in v5***.
>
> Although they may seem more lightweight, they will usually increase the size of node_modules and webpack/rollup bundles in a project that transitively depends on multiple per method packages and/or the main lodash package. Whereas many methods in the main lodash package share code, the per method packages internally bundle copies of any code they depend on.

The docs actually recommend:

> Don't worry—if you import or require methods directly, e.g. `const throttle = require('lodash/throttle')`, only the subset of lodash code your package uses will be bundled in projects that use your package.

Additionally this page has some pretty interesting research into different import options and resulting build sizes: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark

Answer (score 3):

**Best way is with the slash:**

```
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual'  //or equivalent
```

Maybe dotted per function packages were the right answer once, but their use [is now discouraged](https://lodash.com/per-method-packages) and they will be [removed](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3838#issuecomment-398592530).

Also, as stated by [Lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46097962/8082441), it's better than
`import {isEqual} from 'lodash'`, as this will import all lib and *then* extract one function to the current scope.

Answer (score 2):

Lodash lists a couple of options in their [README](https://github.com/lodash/lodash#module-formats):

- [babel-plugin-lodash](https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash)

  - Install lodash and the babel plugin:

  ```
  $ npm i --save lodash
  $ npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-lodash @babel/cli @babel/preset-env
  ```

  - Add this to your `.babelrc`

  ```
  {
    "plugins": ["lodash"],
    "presets": [["@babel/env", { "targets": { "node": 6 } }]]
  }
  ```

  - Transforms this

  ```
  import _ from 'lodash'
  import { add } from 'lodash/fp'

  const addOne = add(1)
  _.map([1, 2, 3], addOne)
  ```

  Roughly to this:

  ```
  import _add from 'lodash/fp/add'
  import _map from 'lodash/map'

  const addOne = _add(1)
  _map([1, 2, 3], addOne)
  ```
- [lodash-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/lodash/lodash-webpack-plugin)

  - Install lodash and webpack plugin:

  ```
  $ npm i --save lodash
  $ npm i --save-dev lodash-webpack-plugin babel-core babel-loader babel-plugin-lodash babel-preset-env webpack
  ```

  - Configure your `webpack.config.js`:

  ```
  var LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require('lodash-webpack-plugin');
  var webpack = require('webpack');

  module.exports = {
    'module': {
      'rules': [{
        'use': 'babel-loader',
        'test': /\.js$/,
        'exclude': /node_modules/,
        'options': {
          'plugins': ['lodash'],
          'presets': [['env', { 'modules': false, 'targets': { 'node': 4 } }]]
        }
      }]
    },
    'plugins': [
      new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin,
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin
    ]
  };
  ```
- [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) using the lodash cli

  - `$ lodash modularize exports=es -o ./`

Answer (score 1):

`import { isEqual } from 'lodash-es';` is importing the entire library. I am using Rollup which should do tree shaking by default.

Whenever I've written my own modules, this named import syntax works and Rollup successfully tree shakes, so I'm a bit confused as to why it won't work with Lodash.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the methods has their own packages. Install the relevant package/method:

```
npm i -S lodash.debounce
npm i -D @types/lodash.debounce
```

Then just import the method and use it

```
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

debounce(() => { ...
```

Also see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a REPL on the browser (chrome dev tools or Deno for example), and you really just need to quickly test something without using any IDE, babel or tool, you can import a single or more lodash functions from almost any website unless they're CORS restricted, in the following way:

```js
(arr => Promise.all(arr.map(_ =>
  import ('https://cdn.skypack.dev/lodash.' + _))).then(_ => _[0].default(arr, _.map(d => d.default))))(
  ["zip", "unzip", "groupby", "mapvalues"])
  .then(_ => Object.fromEntries(_)).then(_ => {
  //you can use _ with zip, unzip, groupby, and mapvalues
  console.log(Object.keys(_))
})
```

Answer (score -2):

this actually worked for me

```
import { isEqual } from 'lodash';
```

Comment: You still get the full lodash library by using this syntax. OP wants to only get the isEqual funtion, reducing the size of his bundle.

Comment: This will import all lib and *then* extract one function to the current scope.