# Importing lodash functions globally in Angular 4 app

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

I'm trying to optimise my Angular 4 application by importing lodash functions globally to the app.module.ts. I tried:

```
import { some } from 'lodash/fp/some';
import _ from 'lodash/wrapperLodash';
```

However, I can't get the reference to that function in a component. This will throw an error:

```
_.some(myVar, { lat: null });
```

My dependencies (the ones related to the topic):

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.104",
"lodash": "^4.17.5",
"typescript": "~2.3.3"
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_lodash_fp_wrapperLodash___default.a.some is not a function
```

Comment: import * as _ from 'lodash'; in this context, 'lodash' will be the npm package

Comment: That way you are importing the whole package. what I'm trying to achieve is to reduce the size of my vendor bundle.

Comment: Ahh so you want to be specific and just bring some in, ok fair enough.

Comment: Ok. So I'm getting kind of error <pre>lodash_wrapperLodash___default.a.find is not a function<code>

Comment: If you only want 'some', you should do: import { some } from 'lodash';

Comment: Posible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479464/how-to-import-single-lodash-function

Comment: Could you please give some example of why you\re using lodash?

Comment: I need those functions: camelCase, cloneDeep, flatten, forEach, includes, some, last, get, mapKeys, toNumber, truncate, union, uniq.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand why people use lodash with all posibilities that ES6 already has.

https://www.sitepoint.com/lodash-features-replace-es6/

But if you want to use it, try to import it in this way:

`import * as _ from "lodash";`

> import * as _ from "lodash";
>   Please note that If you use import _ from
>   “lodash”, you will receive following error that “Module ‘lodash’ has
>   no default export”:

From https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/angular2-import-lodash-into-angular2-application-using-typescript/

Or for just one function of lodash:

```
import wrapperLodash from 'lodash/wrapperLodash';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is to import the whole library. I need to import only particular function and need to do it globally (only once).

Comment: Try this 'import wrapperLodash from 'lodash/wrapperLodash';'

Comment: '_' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479464/how-to-import-single-lodash-function

Comment: exactly... and there is no aswer to this topic.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think that if this stackoverflow link I sent you is not answering your question means that your question is not well related.