# import _merge from 'lodash/merge'; works only on prod but not in dev

Tags: angular, webpack, lodash

While i am using `import _merge from 'lodash/merge'; /** works only on prod **/` i am getting the following error only on DEV:

> bootstrap 353c3e00f9bba3b229e6:21 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):
>   TypeError: merge_1.default is not a function TypeError:
>   merge_1.default is not a function

i fixed that by changing the import statement to:

```
import _merge = require('lodash/merge'); /** works only on dev **/
```

i do not want to load all lodash lib. how can i fixed that so i will not need to change the style of the import statement while changing from dev to prod?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to import single lodash function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479464/how-to-import-single-lodash-function)

Comment: Its not duplication. Here we are talking about something that work on prod but not on dev.