# How to import a single Lodash function in a VueJs project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, lodash

I am trying to import the `debounce` function in my VueJs project.

I ran: `npm i --save lodash.debounce`

Then I imported it in my project with: `import { debounce } from 'lodash/debounce'`

And tried using it with:

```
debounce(() => {
    console.log('I only get fired once every two seconds, max!')
}, 2000)
```

I also tried importing it as `import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'`, but whatever I do I cannot get it to work.

I read this stack post but that also doesn't seem to work: [How to Import a Single Lodash Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479464/how-to-import-a-single-lodash-function)

Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: `import debounce from 'lodash.debounce`'

Comment: Tried that aswell @ShayaUlman. But how do I actually use it in my code? Because the code example that I gave does not run or gives me errors...

Comment: What are the errors? are you sure it eas correctly installed?

Comment: If I use `this.debounce()` the error is: `this.debounce is not a function`, if I just use `debounce()` the error is `"TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"`. I installed it correctly because it is declared in my package.json as a depencency: ` "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",`

Comment: If you write `mounted: { console.log(debounce) }` - What does it print?

Comment: I tested a few different possibilities, and now it prints: 

ƒ debounce(func, wait, options) {
  var lastArgs,
      lastThis,
      maxWait,
      result,
      timerId,
      lastCallTime,
      lastInvokeTime = 0,
      leading = false,
      maxing = false

Which leads me to think that I now imported it properly? It still doesn't log anything tho when the method is called.

Comment: I think, the reason lies in the fact that `debounce(...)` returns a function, which when invoked will actually log what you expect it to log.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is not with importing a single Lodash function,`debounce` just returns a **function** (a new version of the original passed function). To call the original function you need to invoke the function that `debounce` returns.

This is probably what you want:

```html
<script>
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    origFunction() {
      console.log('I only get fired once every two seconds, max!');      
    },
  },
  computed: {
    // Create a debounced function
    // As it is a computed prop it will be cached, and not created again on every call
    debouncedFunction() {
      return debounce(this.origFunction, 2000);
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.debouncedFunction(); // Lodash will make sure thie function is called only once in every 2 seconds    
  }
}
</script>
```

See more in the [Lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce).