# How to replace Lodash's get and set to get and set properties in highly complex objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using `lodash`'s `get` and `set` to manipulate complex objects. Although Lodash is a good library, it also weighs considerably (about 40kb). I am tring to develop a lean web-app, and lodash takes half of the bundle size.

How would you build safe functions that can replace `get` and `set`?

For instance, some function which will change the following object:

**Set**

`const a = {b:2,c:{d:5}}`

`set(a,"c.d",7)`

Which will result

`//a = {b:2,c:{d:7}}`.

if a = {}, it will result:

`{c:{d:7}}`

***Get***

`const a = {b:2,c:{d:5}}`

`let x = get(a,"c.d",0)`

Which will result

`//x = 5` or if the path doesn't exist, `//x = 0`

Comment: You can import lodash functions individually: [How to Import a Single Lodash Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43479464), which will help save on space

Comment: For the get function, you can probably use something like: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491621), you can probably repurpose that for the set function also

Comment: Thanks, I am importing them individually, and yet they take these 40K.

Comment: `lodash.get` should be replaced by optional chaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 2):

You can build a recursive function in JavaScript to do that.

To set the data:

```js
const obj = {b:7,c:{d:{f:8}}};
const set = (string, obj, value) => {
    const [current,...rest] = string.split(".");
    rest.length >= 1 ? set(rest.join("."), obj[current] = obj[current] || {}, value) : obj[current]= value;
    return obj; 
};

console.log(set("c.d.f", obj, 10));
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. seems very smart. I didn't explain it correctly (and now, improved the explanation), I need it to behave like lodash get and set functions. See the above-improved explanation.

Comment: @TalYaron Updated my answer. Take a look. Now this will work even when the object is empty. And for the `get` you can take reference from link which @Nick has commented.

Answer (score 0):

To replace both `_.get()` and `_.set()`, my team has come up with these methods. We have each in its own module and export them as the default method (importing sanitizePath.js into both get.js and set.js), but they can be included in a project in a variety of ways, so I'll present them together:

```
let rgxBracketToDot;

export function sanitizePath (path) {
    path = path || [];
    return Array.isArray(path) ? path : path.replace(rgxBracketToDot || (rgxBracketToDot = /\[(\w+)\]/g), '.$1').split('.');
}

export function get (obj, path) {
    if (!obj || typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return;
    }
    return sanitizePath(path).reduce((acc, val) => acc && acc[val], obj);
}

export function set (obj, path, value) {
    const [current,...rest] = sanitizePath(path);
    rest.length >= 1 ? set(obj[current] = obj[current] || {}, rest, value) : obj[current]= value;
    return obj;
}
```

Note that unlike lodash, `sanitizePath()` as is won't remove leading or trailing dots (.). To remove these and ensure 100% compatibility with lodash, you'll need to include these regex replaces:

```
path = path.replace(/^\./, '');
path = path.replace(/\.$/, '');
```

For maximum performance, it's best to set the regex pattern once in a `let` outside the method in a similar way as `rgxBracketToDot`. As none of the paths in our codebase begin or end with a dot we removed it for our purposes.

Likewise, it's best to only use array paths to avoid having to use `sanitizeString()` altogether. We plan on removing that step as well, but for the time being kept it in order to handle older config files.