# Loop 100 array elements at a time?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, discord.js

I have a commandArray.json file with 300+ comands+imagelinks in the format commandArray[name][response]

I used the code bellow to show users the command names, but its seems i've reached the discord limit of 2000 characters in a single chat message.
So I'm thinking of sending about 100 command names at a time.

Can you help me implement somekind of loop that achieves this?

The code first splits the names and turns the json objects into string and then sorts alphabetically and joins in a string to send the message.

I just need to count 100 names and then send message, and it there are more count again and send and so on.

```
const commandArray = require("./commandArray.json");

if (message.content === '!commands') {
  var addedCommands = commandArray.map(x => `\`${x.name}\``).join(", ")
    var stringArray = addedCommands.split(',');
      var arrangedString = stringArray.sort().join(", ");
        message.channel.send(arrangedString);
```

}

Comment: Please don't make work for other people by vandalizing your posts. Part of the agreement when you signed up for Stack Exchange is to allow Stack Exchange to continue to distribute your posts (which means that vandalism like this is not permitted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const chunkSize = 100, chunks = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(commandArray.length / chunkSize); i++) {
  chunks[i] = commandArray.slice(i*chunkSize, (i+1)*chunkSize);
}
```

Then just operate on `chunks` instead of `commandArray` above, sending each chunk as its own message, e.g. `for (chunk of chunks) ... send(chunk.map().sort().join())`. Also, you don't need the first `.join()` followed by a `.split()`, which does almost nothing here.

Try this:

```js
// outside your message handler...

const commandArray = require("./commandArray.json");
commandArray.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0);

const chunkSize = 100, chunks = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(commandArray.length / chunkSize); i++) {
  chunks[i] = commandArray.slice(i*chunkSize, (i+1)*chunkSize);
}

// inside your message handler function...

if (message.content === '!commands') {
  for (chunk of chunks) {
    message.channel.send(chunk.map(x => `\`${x.name}\``).join(', '));
  }
}
```

Comment: `chunks` isn't a language feature; just an appropriate name I gave to a variable. You only need the array as a string at the very end, where you can join it before sending it to discord. I'll edit my answer to fit it into your code even more.

Answer (score 0):

lodash has a utility called [chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/#chunk) which

> Creates an array of elements split into groups the length of size. If array can't be split evenly, the final chunk will be the remaining elements.

```
import chunk from "lodash.chunk";
const commandArray = require("./commandArray.json");


if (message.content === "!commands") {
  const chunked = chunk(commandArray.sort(), 100);
  chunked.forEach((c, i) => {
    const addedCommands = c.map((x) => `\`${x.name}\``).join(", ");
    message.channel.send(addedCommands);
  });
}
```

[image: Edit morning-cloud-90tke]

Comment: You would have to install the dependency before using it. Does it work for you in the sandbox?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479464/how-to-import-a-single-lodash-function